# Cant install chrome no matter what I try. DPKG keeps returning errors

Tags: google-chrome, dpkg, browser, google

This is the code I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
dpkg: error processing package network-manager (--configure):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
network-manager
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be related with another package - namely `network-manager`. Have you tried to do as the message tells you? As in doing a reinstall of network-manager via: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager` - before you do anything else`

Comment: Sidenote: there is `google-chrome` and `chromium-browser` - just to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install network-manager
```